# Let $1=<a_1<a_2<...<a_k=n$ all the divisors of a number n. Find all possible values of n such that $n={a_2}^2+{a_3}^3$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, divisibility

This problem is stated as follows:

> Let $1=a_1<a_2<a_3<...<a_k=n$ be the divisors of a positive integer $n$. Find all $n$ such that $n={a_2}^2+{a_3}^3$

I have some issues understanding this problem and would like to see some approaches to it.

Comment: I don't understand.  if you take $n=96$, then you don't get $a_2^2+a_3^2=n$.

Comment: Notice that that $96$ is not a possible answer, because in this case we have $a_2 = 2$ and $a_3 = 3$, but $a_2^2 + a_3^3 = 31 \neq 96$.

Comment: That's right! Whoops that was embarrassing

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The only such $n$ is $68$

To see this, note that $a_2=p$ must be the least prime that divides $n$.  But then $$n=p^2+a_3^3\implies p\,|\,a_3\implies a_3=p^2$$

But in that case we must have $$n=p^2+p^6=p^2(1+p^4)$$

Now, if $p$ were odd then $1+p^4$ would be even, whence $2\,|\,n$ contradicting the minimal property of $p$.  Thus $p=2$ and $$n=4+64=68$$

Answer (score 1):

$n$ cannot be prime because there would not be a value for $a_3$.  $a_2$ has to be the smallest prime dividing $n$.  $a_3$ can either be the second smallest prime dividing $n$ or $a_2^2$.  We can look at each case.

In the first case, call the primes $p,q$.  Then we are given $n=p^2+q^3$.  If $p,q$ are coprime, $n$ will be coprime to both and they cannot be factors of $n$ so this case is impossible.

In the second case, call the prime $p$ and we are given $n=p^2+p^6$.  Any other prime dividing $n$ must be greater than $p^2$.  If $p$ is odd, $n$ is even and has a factor $2$ which is less than $p$.  The only solution is $p=2, a_2=2,a_3=4,n=68=2^2\cdot 17$ and $17 \gt 2^2$

Answer (score 0):

$a_2$ must be prime and then from $a_2\mid n-a_2^2=a_3^3$, we conclude that $a_2\mid a_3$. This is only possible if $a_3=a_2^2$. Then $n=p^2+p^3=p^2(p+1)$ for some prime $p$. However, this makes $n$ even so that necessarily $p=2$ and $n=12$.

Comment: No...we get $n=p^2+p^6$.